# Connecting to SQL Server 2000 through TCP/IP on localhost failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, tcp

I have tried to connect to SQL Server 2000 through TCP/IP.

I followed [these steps](http://ww2.recruitmentsystems.com.au/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=32) and enabled SQL Server 2000 on port 1433.

Then I used the command to test whether the port is opened up:

```
telnet localhost 1433
```

But I found the following error:

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: 
Connect failed
```

And I also failed to connect to the server by following [these steps](http://aquesthosting.com/SQL2000RemoteConnection).

How to solve this problem and connect to Sql Server 2000 through TCP/IP?

See my configs

[image]
[image]

Comment: i am also getting the same error. Please tell how you solved it.

Comment: images are broken... and so does the link to the config-steps

Answer (score 1):

By default TCP-IP is disabled.
You need run SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration and enable the protocol, then restart SQL Server service

Comment: I have restarted my PC and the SQL Server. But it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, have you enable TCP-IP in Configuration Manager?
Try do disable other protocols, leave only TCP-IP. So if you will be able to connect it has to be TCP-IP

Answer (score 1):

Try disable your firewall temporarily and see if it makes a difference, to isolate the problem.

EDIT: Wait, did you enable TCP/IP on the *client* or *server* ? If you only enabled it on the client, then that explains it.

It must be enabled on *both* to allow communication. From your error, it looks like the server does not accept TCP connections. I don't remember what SQL 2000 calls the program, but find something like "SQL Server Network Configuration", *not* "Client Configuration". And turn on TCP there.

Perhaps show us a screenshot of your network configuration dialog.

Comment: I have enabled TCP in both client and server through Client Network Util and Server network Util respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I did following actions to remove this bug

1)**Disable** Other Protocols other than **TCP/IP** from **SQL Server Client And Server Utilities**

2)Re-Instal **SQL Server 2000 sp4**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be running SQL Server Agent to connect via TCP/IP on 2000.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929152

Use an alternative representation of the name of the local host address instead of "localhost". Possible alternative representations include the following:

- 127.0.0.1
- "."
- The actual local host name

Answer (score 0):

Installed SQL Server 2000 SP4 and it solved the problem for me.